# How i can solve problems with jqGrid sorting, paging?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

Ok i change server side code to

```
  int nm = objects.ToList().Count;
  if (objects.ToList().Count > 0)
       return new PagedList(objects, nm, 1, 25, null);
  else return null;
```

json is change to

{"d":{"total":15,"page":1,"records":366,"rows":[{"id":"34324","LastDateChange":"/Date(1391464800000)/","DateLoad":"/Date(1391464800000)/"....,"AName":"fg"}],"userData":null}}

client side

```
   $("#table").jqGrid({
    url: '/WebSrv.asmx/GetSaleObjects',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    loadonce: true,
   ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
   serializeGridData: function (postData) {
   },
   viewrecords: true,
   sortable: true,
   gridview: true,
   multisort: true,
   height: 'auto',
   width: 'auto',
   pager: "#pgrf",
   autowidth: true,
   pagination: true,
    jsonReader: {
       root: "d.rows",
       page: "d.page",
       total: "d.total",
       records: "d.records"
   }
 ....
   });
```

but grid is empty! don`t uderstand ;( , may be sample ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you get very very old example as the template for your solution. The option `imgpath` for example is deprecated (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aupgrade_from_3.4.x_to_3.5#options)) already in version 3.5. So you used template created for at leas 5 yeas old version of jqGrid.

Another important bug in your code is the usage of manual JSON serialization inside of ASMX web service method. You should remove call of `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject` from the `GetSaleObjects`. The method should return `PagedList` object or just `Object`. By the way you can return `objects` (or `objects.ToList()`) instead of `new PagedList(objects, objects.ToList().Count, 1, objects.ToList().Count)` in case of usage `loadonce: true` because jqGrid **ignores `page`, `records` and `total`** parts of the server response in case of `loadonce: true`.

It's important to understand that current code serializes the results to JSON **twice**. So you have to call `JSON.parse` inside of `success` handle of `$.ajax`. For example if you have an `new PagedList(...)` object then the firs serialization to JSON produce the string like

```js
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":350,"rows":[...]}
```

ASP.NET serialize **additionally** the returned results. So one modify the returned value to the string

```js
"{\"total\":1,\"page\":1,\"records\":350,\"rows\":[...]}"
```

Deserialization of correct JSON string (`{"total":1,"page":1,"records":350,"rows":[...]}`) will produce the object with properties `total`, `rows` etc. on the client side . On the other side deserialization of the wrong string (`{\"total\":1,\"page\":1,\"records\":350,\"rows\":[...]}`) produce **the string** which contains the text `{"total":1,"page":1,"records":350,"rows":[...]}`. Only if one apply additional call of `jQuery.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse` one will get required *object*.